# Is there anything like SubString or Split function for String Array too?

Tags: c#, .net, string

When I have a string, I can use the `Substring()` or `Split()` functions and store the result into a `string` or `string[]` respectively.

I want to treat below **string array** same way as with **string**.

+-----------------------------------------------+
| $ | $ | Name | $ | $ |NIC| $ | $ |Gender |
+-----------------------------------------------+

How it is possible?

Comment: hi  could you  explain more

Comment: You've provided some sample input; how about some sample output?

Comment: am i supposed to assume that the '|' character you are using is separating your string?

Comment: Explain what you mean with _"treat below string array same way as with string"_. Do you want to call `SubString()` or `Split()` on each string in your array? Then try a [loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e10e56(v=vs.90).aspx) or [`stringArray.Select(s => s.SubString(...))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Sure. Thanks for pointing. I would like to have output what is _between_ `Name and NIC` and what is _between_ `NIC and Gender` @Austin and @BRAHIM

Comment: No, Thats poor tho but I tried to represent array in this form. If x is array then x[0]=$,x[1]=$.....x[x.length]=Gender. @Nicolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of getting what's between NIC & Gender:

```
var betweenNicAndGender = stringArray.SkipWhile(s => !s.Equals("NIC"))
                                     .Skip(1) // skip NIC
                                     .TakeWhile(s => !s.Equal("Gender"));
```

Comment: Thanks, can `.TakeWhile()` have more than one conditions inside? e.g `.TakeWhile(s => !s.Equal("Gender") OR s => !s.Equal("Age"))`

Comment: @Austin-- It gives error. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq The syntax is: `.TakeWhile(s => !s.Equals("Gender") || !s.Equals("???"));`

Answer (score 2):

The best solution depends on the problem you're actually trying to solve and the size of your data. It wouldn't hurt to have a look at the standard LINQ methods (Skip, Take) and Array.IndexOf of course.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> | $ | $ | Name | $ | $ |NIC| $ | $ |Gender |
> ```
>
> I would like to have output what is between Name and NIC and what is between NIC and Gender

Something like this:

```
int firstIndex  = stringArray.IndexOf("Name");
int secondIndex = stringArray.IndexOf("NIC");

var result = input.Skip(firstIndex + 1).Take(secondIndex - firstIndex)
```

Adding error checking is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string[] SubstringArray(string[] inputArray, int index, int count)
{ 
    string[] result = new string[count];

    for(int i = index; i < count+index; i++)
        result[i - index] = inputArray[i];

    return result;
}

public List<string[]> SplitStringArray(string[] inputArray, string splitter)
{
    List<string[]> splitResult = new List<string[]>();
    List<string> tempString = new List<string>();

    foreach(string x in inputArray)
    {
        if(x == splitter)
        {
            splitResult.add(tempString.ToArray());
            tempString = new List<string>();
        }
        else
        {
            tempString.add(x);
        }
    }
    return splitResult;
}
```

Comment: Your second function uses splitResult of type List<string[]>. The string[] could be string here as you are not adding more than one element to the string[] array.

Comment: I was intending to have x added to `tempString` if it wasn't a splitter and when a splitter is encountered add the accumulated list tempString to splitResult as an array and "reset" tempString as an empty list.  May run into issues reaching the end of inputArray or if no splitters are present in inputArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use

```
string.Join("", yourarrayName);
```

Comment: That will just paste the string that was just split back together. I think OP wants to perform a certain split operation for each string in an array.